# How to delete directory containing files in the assets directory in Android

Tags: java, android, file, assets

How could you delete a directory containing files on android assets directory.

I tried doing this but does not work.

```
try {
         listaAssets = getAssets().list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

for(String s : listaAssets){
     deleteFolder(s)
}

public void deleteFolder(String path){
    File folder = new File(path);
    File [] list;
    int num =0;
    boolean del = false;
    try{
        list = folder.listFiles();
        num = list.length;
        for (int i = 0; i<num; i++){
            list[i].delete();
        }
        if(folder.delete()){
            del = true;
        }else{
            del = false;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR","Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Error: null

Comment: What is the actual exception thrown? Using `e.printStackTrace();` would be probably more useful then logging `e.getMessage()` when the message is empty. On what line does the exception occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could you delete a directory containing files on android assets directory.

You cannot delete (or modify) assets at runtime. They are read-only.

Comment: Ok, I was looking for a specific answer but could not find it. thanks.